# PHP to Java communication

Tags: java, php, communication

I want to use PHP to communicate with a java using shared database to communicate, please help me with sample code or logic.

Thank you.

EDIT:

I appreciate your suggestions, Yes I will be using both php and java to connect to thesame database.

The issue I'm faced with is that I want to know, do I have to create generic command that will be used for the communication? I'm trying to avoid dirty codes and ensure good programming techniques.

Comment: Are you saying you want to use the same database with a php program and a java program?

Comment: If youre using the db essentially as a message transport layer then there isnt much of a sampel we can give you... you jsut need to access the database in each application and do whatever you need to do with the data. If you're having a specific problem edit the question with details about that problem.

Comment: Or if you're really just looking for a message queue, you could just use a message queueing system like activemq.

Answer (score 1):

For sure.
Take a look this, will help you:

http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/

Answer (score 1):

Facebook developed [Thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/) for doing exactly what you are looking for.

Hope this helps
Daniel