# Notify a running Java process with PHP

Tags: java, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I communicate between PHP and a Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350231/how-can-i-communicate-between-php-and-a-java-program)

I'm currently writing a web service which needs to handle events in real time.
So I thought it would be a nice approach to write a java program which runs in the background and handles all the events.

So the frontend of the web application is written in PHP. The user creates a new event and what I want is, that that PHP script notifies the running java process about that event. Is this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5517156/622470
and
http://stackoverflow.com/q/3350231/622470

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly send web service request from your PHP code to your Java application by making it a web service provider.

Other then web services there are couple of more alternatives:

- [PHP Java Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/)
- [Thrift](http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/)
- Send a low level socket (TCP/IP) message from PHP to Java

Also here is a good [tutorial on integrating Java with PHP using Thrift](http://gauravasthana.blogspot.com/2010/12/using-thrift-with-java-and-php.html)

Comment: Wow Thrift seems pretty great. Thank you for your hint.